# wp_list_bookmarks display

Tags: get-bookmarks

I have a question about code on wordpress:  I am trying to use code wp_list_bookmarks to list my featured communities that I have setup in "links categories."  I want to be able to separate each link like the following:

San Diego | La Jolla | Rancho Santa Fe | Del Mar

I am currently using: `<?php wp_list_bookmarks('title_li=&category_before=&category_after=&category=21'); ?>`

It does work, but displays like this:

- San Diego
- La Jolla
- Rancho Santa Fe
- Del Mar

Again, I want this:

San Diego | La Jolla | Rancho Santa Fe | Del Mar

Any code recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Not extremely elegant, but should work...

```
$sep = " | ";
$args = array(
    'before'=>'',
    'after'=>$sep,
    'category_after'=>'',
    'category_before'=>'',
    'title_li'=>'',
    'echo'=>0     //return the string, don't echo
);
$str = wp_list_bookmarks($args);
//chop off the last separator...
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - strlen($sep));
echo $str;
```

EDIT --
I added `before` and `after` to the `$args` array -- these are actually what `_walk_bookmarks()` uses before and after each link.

Comment: woops.  I screwed up.  Editing...